# Dim when not configuring any GPIO pins; why?

Tags: gpio, led, voltage

I am an absolute beginner with the Raspberry pi and also know only basic electronics, so please excuse me if this is a very basic question.

I wired my Raspberry pi 4 like this to control an RGB LED.

[image]

When I connect everything, and dont configure any of my GPIO pins, the LED still glows very lightly.
When I set up all GPIO pins I use to HIGH, the LED goes completely out.

I understand that the LED is out as soon a s I set the GPIO pins to high, because they output 3.3V, so so there shouldn't flow any electricity.

My question here is, why the LED also dimly lights up when I do not configure any GPIO pins. Does this mean that the "default/standard" current of the GPIO pin is something between 0 and 3.3V?

Furthermore, I was wondering if there is a benefit of wiring the LED like this, e.g. HIGH voltage output -> LED goes out.

My amateur intuition would say that it would make more sense to wire it so that a HIGH output would turn the LED on.

Also: is it dangerous to directly connect the 3.3V output with one of the GPIO pins? Should I always include a resistor?

If anyone could answer any of my questions, I would be very thankful!

Cheers!

Comment: Perhaps because all those GPIO's are pulled down inputs unless set otherwise

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour.

The weak pull-downs may provide sufficient current to glow dimly ~ 50µA.

You could disable pull-downs in your code.

It is normal practice to wire this way.

You would need different LED to use otherwise.

"Should I always include a resistor?" Strictly NO - but you do need some form of current limiting, and this is usually provided by a resistor.

You could use a single resistor in the common anode but this is only effective if lighting LED one at a time e.g. traffic light.

Comment: do you mean pull-downs?